# How to translate Java lambda predicate to Postgres?

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, lambda

I want to write a service with the following API

```
List<Device> getDevices(Predicate<? super T> filter)
```

I want to call it like: `getDevices(device -> device.osNum > 4)`

My service will query an SQL DB (apparently [Postgres](http://postgresguide.com/utilities/psql.html)).

Is there any library to translate the lambda expression to query in Postgres (or other) RDBMS?

If I use `Hibernate`, I should get all the devices (20 max) and run the lambda on that collection?

Other design suggestion?

Comment: It's not exactly what you are looking for, but take a look at [jOOQ](http://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/sql-statements/select-statement/where-clause/).

Comment: No, that's not possible. The lambda is just an instance of Predicate. The receiving method doesn't know anything about its conditions: only that it can ask the predicate if a T is accepted or not. But yes, if the device table has just 20 rows, getting everything and applying the predicate in memory isn't likely to cause any performance problem (unless of course it loads a shitload of toMany associations)

Answer (score 2):

There is actually a library called [Jinq](http://www.jinq.org/index.html) (Java Linq, I think) that does something similar to what you want. What it does internally is analyzing the bytecode generated from the passed lambda expression.

There is a nice [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JqCnZFzTR2I) on their site.